# Displaying report quarterly in access

Tags: ms-access

So I have this query that has 52 weeks, I was wondering is it possible to display these weeks quarterly to a report? Is there a way it will automate quarterly and display those reports?

Comment: You're providing us with very little information, so I'm inclined to just say yes and leave it at that. You can just filter the query, and select a range of weeks you want. Search online for how to filter a query.

Comment: Yes, but you will have to specify a rule for which weeks should be included, as weeks don't follow neither months nor years.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a field that calculates a quarterly identifier and use that constructed field to group and sort records.

If you have a date/time field, can let Access assign the quarter with:

`DatePart("q", [fieldname])`

Or if you want to use an alternate year such as Oct-Sep fiscal.

`Switch(Month([fieldname]),<=3,3, Month([fieldname])<=6,4, Month([fieldname])<=9,1, Month([fieldname])<=12,2, True, 0)`

If you have a field with a week number, consider:

`Switch([fieldname]<=13,1, [fieldname]<=26,2, [fieldname] <= 39,3, [fieldname] <=52,4, True,0)`

Or as Erik said, filter by a range of weeks.

Comment: It cannot be done that simple as both first and last week mostly cross calendar year boundaries.

Comment: Using DatePart to define the week number can be an issue, but my suggestion assumes user has assigned a week number - maybe like a pay period ID.

Comment: But even the assigned week number might not exactly fit the 3-month quarters defined in the expression. There might be a shift each year because of variable month lengths. This can be seen in payroll systems based on 2-week cycle. A couple of months will have 3 pay checks and which months shifts each year.

Comment: Sure, but you will have to have a rule for the week distribution to work after.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an actual Access Report object (not a form) and your dates align with standard quarterly periods (Jan to Mar, Apr to Jun, etc.), you can create a report that is grouped by quarters of the date field.  Create a new report and specify the record source as you normally would.

1. On the Report Design ribbon (a.k.a. Toolbar), click the Group & Sort button.

   - A docked panel will appear below the report design area, labeled "*Group, Sort, and Total*".
2. Click "Add Group" in the *Group, Sort and Total* panel.
3. Choose a date field from the drop-down field list.
4. Click the button labeled "More >"
5. Ensure that the grouping is "by quarter" (which is always the default that I've observed)
6. Format the report according to your design, but you'll probably at least want a group header indicating the quarter.

   - Add a control for your quarter date to the group header.
   - Edit that control's Format property to something like `"Quarter "q", Year "yyyy`. Anything in double quotes is literal and the lone `q` is a placeholder for the quarter number.

     7. Layout fields in the detail section as you would any other report.